# Find linear subsets in a 2D point (xy) data

Tags: r, spatial, pattern-recognition, trend

My problem is the very idea of how to start the analysis of 2D point patterns, specifically how to find linear trends within their spatial pattern.

I have XY data points which are organized like in the plot, which I have manually marked with red lines in order to highlight what should be determined:

[image]

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82598/clustering-2d-data-using-kernel-density-methods) suggests the use of kernel density estimation (which is the usual method I guess), but I would like to find out if there is any simpler way of doing this, avoiding the use of spatial statistics. R solution is preferred.

**UPDATE:**

When using the solution suggested by whuber (Hough transform) I get these lines as the most frequent ones in my scatterplot:

[image]

Obviously these are not the lines I was searching for, but nevertheless it would be interesting to determine the very points that lie on the red line, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure why the "This should be found" line doesn't continue to the bottom right of the graph.

Comment: It can continue in a linear regression fashion I guess, but the point is that only the points that are directly on it should be detected. If too long it may include more points further down to the bottom right.

Comment: For additional solutions, please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109819 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33078.

Comment: Yes I have looked at the solutions proposed, but I`m still slightly unsure how to detect precisely which points share a linear trend, since they may not lie in a perfectly straight line? Otherwise the usage of Hough transform is a great idea. Thanks.